# How to reinstall MiKTeX

Tags: installing, miktex

I want to re-install my MiKTeX distribution on my computer. What would be the most advisable way of doing it? What is the process of uninstalling the previous version safely and installing the new one?

Comment: To make sure to get rid of all traces of MiKTeX before reinstalling, you can use the [IObit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.php) to uninstall, and tools like [Advanced SystemCare 6 Free](http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.php) or [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MiKTeX has no own button or menu to uninstall it.

To be sure to uninstall MiKTeX completely just use the "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" control panel to delete MiKTeX.

Then reboot your computer.

Then download and install the new MiKTeX from the homepage http://www.miktex.org.

*Why the reboot?*

The reboot is necessary because the architecture of windows. There is a problem with loading dll's. That is only done by starting windows new (reboot). So if you want to unload earlier loaded dll's you **have** to reboot. If you forget it your computer can show malfunctions or freezes or can run without problems (if the loaded old dll's do not disturb your running programs). It is better to reboot after uninstalling a software on Windows ...

Comment: Is the reboot necessary and what would it cause if this is not done? Cause I forgot to reboot.....lol. I see that the menu under program no longer appears lol