# Cannot change package repositories

Tags: errors, moderncv, miktex2.9, repositories

Good afernoon everyone! I downloaded some packages from [ctan.org](https://ctan.org) and installed it with miktex settings, but as I understand it is not a good idea, so I decided to download packages from some repositories. Unfortunately, I do not use proxy that's why I have this error

[image]

How can I begin to use any repositories? I tried to install moderncv, but it needs a lot of packages and as a result, there are a lot of errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to download the packages?  Often, the installation will bring along all the packages you would need.  What packages is it trying to download?

Comment: @Teepeemm I try to work with moderncv. I downloaded it and installed by hand with miktex setting. So it only can install packages from computer. Then latex said that it needed other packages like colortbl, fancyhdr, Unicode.txt, etc. But now it has a lot of mistakes and the files with moderncv are not compiled.

Comment: You may need to reinstall Miktex https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138697/91556

Comment: @hesham ok, thanks! I realized that it is the only solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments